# How to click on a link with Selenium with href="javascript:__doPostBack

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, dopostback

I tried to click link from selenium.webdriver but I got it nothing. Can please help with this issue

Page contains the following elements:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack("m_m_cBody_bdy_uc_tbl$Edit","13911")"> Details </a>
```

My target to click:

> "m_m_cBody_bdy_uc_tbl$Edit","13911"

Please note that I have many text links with

> Details

is not a unique element on my page

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack("m_m_cBody_bdy_uc_tbl$Edit","41946")"> 
Details </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *normalize-space()*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[normalize-space()='Details' and contains(@href, '13911')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *contains()*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Details') and contains(@href, '13911')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I have many  text links with Details  is Not a unique element
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack("m_m_cBody_bdy_uc_tbl$Edit","13911")"> Details </a>
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack("m_m_cBody_bdy_uc_tbl$Edit","15916")"> Details </a>

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Did you try out the modified lines of code? Can you let me know the result?